# How come the "Learning to write a compiler" question was deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Great Question Deletion Audit of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012)

I've just noticed that the question [Learning to Write a Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler) has been deleted and I wondered why?

Personally (as someone interested in learning more about compiler development) I found this question extremely useful and its the only place I know of on in the internet where I can find such an extensive list of resources on the topic.

I also use this question as an "exact duplicate" close target whenever someone asks a vague question about writing a parser or a compiler.

If there is a problem with the wording of the question then is there something that can be done to fix it so that it can be un-deleted?

Comment: @casperOne -- How is this a duplicate **at all**??

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Did you see link?  It's about what happened to that question and a number of others like that.  Note you and others can also vote to reopen if you really feel that the question around *this* particular post is *so* special that it warrants it's own answer posting to what I'm saying is the duplicated post.

Comment: @casperOne I think you might have the wrong definition of what *duplicated post* means...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA And yet you *still* haven't voted to reopen...

Comment: @casperOne there **voted** happy? That still does not change the fact that you are using a misconstrued definition of *duplicate*

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I'd be happier if you worked with the system *first* instead of against it.  Starting a mini-rant in the comments doesn't really work.  Just get a few others to reopen and then all's well with the world.  Go to Tavern on the Meta and ask.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: I think its duped as that question already covers this one.  If you read the question, you'll see that the LtWaC question was migrated to the [compiler tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/compiler/info)

Comment: @Won't I **do not** see it in the wiki, unless I am looking wrong (which is always possible).

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Oh, well, not *everything* is in there, but the selected answer, the "big list of resources" is in there.

Answer (score 7):

Contents have been moved to the [compiler](/questions/tagged/compiler) wiki, as you can see in this question: [The Great Question Deletion Audit of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012)