# Define "Duplicate" in the context of meta

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The following question was closed as a ***duplicate*** by a *randomMod ♦*:
[How come the "Learning to write a compiler" question was deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123948/155556)

How is this a duplicate at all?
What I see is an someone who asked for an answer to his/her question and got an answer for it.
Why was it *dubbed* a duplicate of [The Great Question Deletion Audit of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012)  when it was nothing of the sort?

What ***defines*** a *duplicate*? Who defines what it is?

I was always under the assumption that a **duplicate** was a question that asked basically the same thing as the OP, which was not the case in the aforementioned OP.

---

*Related*:

- [When is a duplicate question not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12182/155556)
- [Screenshot of comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKBBm.png)

Comment: If you're going to bring this up, please include the [last comment I made in response to you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123948/how-come-the-learning-to-write-a-compiler-question-was-deleted#comment331035_123948) - Omitting it is, shall we say, willfully omitting information to support your position.

Comment: @casperOne I got that comment **after** I posted this question.

Comment: @casperOne also noone was in the tavern, I had checked.

Comment: Then I urge you to edit the question, as well as the screen shot to update accordingly as the comment was created three minutes before you posted this (not after you posted this in an attempt to save face).

Comment: @casperOne I am not sure why, it does not add any context. And as you know, this is a *community* driven site, so you can edit just as well as I can.

Comment: Absolutely, but would almost be unethical, given that you are lodging a specific complaint against *me* (indirectly or not).  No need for rollback wars or "power-mad" mods or any crap like that here.

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that you're using a very specific example, *and* making it very personal (by unnecessarily including the comment war going on).  The example is fine, and the question (conceptually) is a pefectly valid one to discuss on here.  I think you might need to calm down a little and spend some more time thinking about the post / formulating your argument before posting stuff like this immediately.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I do not mean to make it personal at all. sorry if it seems that way...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I've made an edit to try and make the post less argumentative.  Please roll it back if you're not comfortable with the change.

Comment: BTW, in all seriousness, [I see what you did there with "randomMod", very clever play on "casperOne" (same letter count, same casing)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/123958/2), or maybe it just worked out that way.  I chuckled.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I fixed your edit up a bit ^_^

Comment: @casperOne haha I did not even see that lol Maybe I was thinking it in my head :-P

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123665/should-duplicate-standards-be-different-on-meta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Closing as a duplicate on meta has for a long time included cases where an answer explains what the asker is looking for, since so many posts are [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). For example, if somebody asks what the rep cap is, it's probably going to get closed as a duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). It's an entirely different question, but that question exists to be the central source of information on reputation; we don't need a separate post just to cover a tiny aspect of it

Similarly, [The Great Question Deletion Audit of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012) exists to discuss old popular questions that the mods are planning to delete. This is rather a good idea since those deletions tend to be controversial, and this way they can just direct people who complain there and say "look, we already covered it". There's no need to discuss each deletion separately when they've already been discussed in one place and were all deleted for similar reasons